# why cursive font does not Works in my browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, cursive

i have a paragraphe into my html code, i try to change the font family to cursive by using CSS,
when i open this page in tablet its works perfectly and the font is change like i want ,but it's not works correctly in my browser google chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Build officiel) (64 bits)(windows 10),
how i can add this font to my browser for getting the same result That appeared in tablet?

```css
p{
font-family:cursive;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem
</p>
```

Comment: You have to find wich font it is and import it

Comment: i know That it's belong to cursive font-family, i have Built an apk from this code using cordova, its Works correctly in tablet, but it not give the same result in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the font using [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) or something similar. This is also why it's important to have a generic font-family as a fallback mechanism in case the specified font is unavailable. So in the code below we are providing `sans-serif` as a generic font-family in case Georgia is unavailable.

```
font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
```